# How to receive ChatGPT multi-line replies when using CURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, curl, gpt-3

The code below works. The problem is when ChatGPT replies only 1 line is rendered to the terminal and the rest of the text is cut off. I am not familiar with curl commands. How do I update the code so that multi-line replies are rendered?

**EDIT:**  I tried console.log() the response inside the express post request believing that CURL was the problem. It appears **CURL is not the problem** and ChatGPT simply cuts off mid reply

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: "my-api-key",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// Set up the server
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

// Set up the ChatGPT endpoint
app.post("/chat", async (req, res) => {
  // Get the prompt from the request
  const { prompt } = req.body;

  // Generate a response with ChatGPT
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    prompt: prompt,
  });

  console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text) // still cuts off
  res.send(completion.data.choices[0].text);
});

// Start the server
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"prompt":"Hello, how are you doing today?"}' http://localhost:8080/chat
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this api, but does the `choices` array have more than one element?

Comment: The code looks almost identical to the code from this page https://www.codingthesmartway.com/how-to-use-chatgpt-with-react/ . (apparently the only difference is the addition of `console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text) // still cuts off`) (If you aren't the author this code you should give proper attribution, otherwise it's plagiarism. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

The `completion.data.choices[0].text` response a multiple lines with `\n`

You needs to call matched API with multiple lines curl call.

I tested OpenAI example , called [`Natural language to Stripe API`](https://beta.openai.com/examples)
[image]
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: "*********** your API Key ***********",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// Set up the server
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

// Set up the ChatGPT endpoint
app.post("/chat", async (req, res) => {
    // Get the prompt from the request
    const { prompt } = req.body;

    // Generate a response with ChatGPT
    const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: prompt,
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 100,
        top_p: 1.0,
        frequency_penalty: 0.0,
        presence_penalty: 0.0,
        stop: ["\"\"\""],
    });

    console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text)
    res.send(completion.data.choices[0].text)
});

// Start the server
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

`curl` command

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"prompt": "\"\"\"\nUtil exposes the following:\n\nutil.stripe() -> authenticates & returns the stripe module; usable as stripe.Charge.create etc\n\"\"\"\nimport util\n\"\"\"\nCreate a Stripe token using the users credit card: 5555-4444-3333-2222, expiration date 12 / 28, cvc 521\n\"\"\""}' http://localhost:8080/chat
```

Response in terminal

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"prompt": "\"\"\"\nUtil exposes the following:\n\nutil.stripe() -> authenticates & returns the stripe module; usable as stripe.Charge.create etc\n\"\"\"\nimport util\n\"\"\"\nCreate a Stripe token using the users credit card: 5555-4444-3333-2222, expiration date 12 / 28, cvc 521\n\"\"\""}' http://localhost:8080/chat
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   449  100   159  100   290     53     98  0:00:03  0:00:02  0:00:01   152

token = stripe.Token.create(
    card={
        "number": "5555-4444-3333-2222",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 28,
        "cvc": 521
    },
)
```

Server side response

```
$ node server.js
Server listening on port 8080


token = stripe.Token.create(
    card={
        "number": "5555-4444-3333-2222",
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 28,
        "cvc": 521
    },
)
```

Comment: OP is directly accessing ChatGPT's internal requests using cURL. They're not using an official API.